# Canvas covers page in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, canvas

I'm centering my canvas using this code:

```
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin-top:-200px; /* Half of canvas height */
margin-left:-275px; /* Half of canvas width */
```

It works perfect in all browsers except for IE9 and 10. In Internet Explorer, it covers the whole page. Is it possible to support the centering the canvas in IE?

Comment: Did you specify a width in CSS as well?

Comment: @Pete http://pastebin.com/wMz33J5Q

Comment: @user1431627 do you need absolute positioning?

Comment: @sylwia I need it because if it isn't there, it goes up to the left corner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Centring using `margin: 0 auto;` with `display: block;` works in almost all browser - the ones that support `<canvas>` for sure.

Live example: http://jsbin.com/ovoziv/2

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Centring Canvas</title>
</head>
<body>

  <canvas></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
canvas {
  display: block;
  background: #FFFFB7;
  width: 550px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**EDIT: Updated answer to center vertically too. This CSS will do the trick:**

```
canvas {
    background-color: #FFFFB7;
    width: 550px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -275px;
    margin-top: -200px;
}
```

Now the explanation. We first place the canvas with 50% offset from the top and left-side using `position: absolute` by setting `top` and `left` to `50%`. Then, because your canvas has a static size, we add a negative margin (which you should never do when the element is not absolute positioned) for half of the width and size (550x400/2 = 275x200): `margin-left: -275px; margin-top: -200px;`.

The canvas will now be displayed at the center of the screen. If you do this inside another element and want to center in that one, try adding `position: relative;` to that element, so it will use it's bounds instead of the body's.

Live example here: http://jsbin.com/ovoziv/6

Comment: But it's not vertically centered, only horizontal.

Comment: @user1431627 I updated my answer. It's basically your code, but seems to work anyway..

Comment: I figured out the problem. The IE settings were set to zoom the whole page in. Embarrasing :P